# Is there a way to extract contents from a JSON list inside a pandas dataframe cell?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that contains JSONs just like the example below. I want to extract just the zipcode value from either of the banks, but I can't.

```
[{"Bank1":{"zipcode":"045603", "total_amount":"400000"}}, {"Bank2":{"{"zipcode":"07069", "total_amount":"890000"}}]
```

I tried doing the following, which would work if it wasn't a JSON list, I believe:

```
df['bank1_zipcode'] = df['bank_data'].str['Bank1'].str['zipcode']
```

But had no success.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use map

`df['bank_data'].map(lambda x: x['Bank1']['zipcode'])`

Comment: I've tried this, it returns the following error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, any idea why?

Comment: can you show `df['bank_data'].head()`

Answer (score 0):

It's a list, try

```py
df['bank1_zipcode'] = df['bank_data'].str[0].str['Bank1'].str['zipcode']
```